# Typescript compiler failing with different property types on Omit and index signature

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to use a sub type with properties omitted and assign it to its parent type using a generic index signature.  I'm trying to understand why it will let this happen **only if** the properties are of the same type.

For example, this is all good:

```
interface Obj {
  foo: number
  bar: number
  baz: number
}
type Sub = Omit<Obj, "baz">

let obj: Obj = {foo: 1, bar: 1, baz: 1}

function fn <K extends keyof Sub>(key: K, val: Sub[K]) {
  obj[key] = val
}
```

And on this one the compiler complains that "Type 'Sub[K]' is not assignable to type 'Obj[K]'.
Property 'baz' is missing in type 'Sub' but required in type 'Obj'"

```
interface Obj {
  foo: number
  bar: string
  baz: number
}
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `keyof Sub` and therefore `K` is of type `"foo" | "bar"`. That means that `Sub[K]` is of type `string | number`; the types of values that the entries with keys "foo" and "bar" contain.

`string | number` is not a type that's going to be assignable to much of anything useful. I'm sure there's an alternative solution that will work for what you're trying to accomplish, but as things are now, this seems like a bit of an XY problem.

Update: What I said above, while true, missed the point of the question. I'm leaving this up for the sake of the conversation in the comments, in case that helps someone else come across the correct answer.

Comment: Hi Nathan thanks for responding. I'm aware that Sub[K] switches from string to string | number. Typescript could handle inferring the type by using the key prior to the Omit, so I don't understand why it's unable to use the same logic after the Omit.  The app is looping through a long list of properties with different types on the object, then handling the values differently based on their type, and this is the only way to handle it properly.  I could cast the key into the parent (Obj) schema and it works just fine (which is also string | number ), but that's just a hack

Comment: So it can! Very cool, I didn't realize TS could do that. You can also cast `obj` to a `Sub` which might be a little cleaner and feel less hacky.

Comment: That would make it easier, unfortunately I'm trying to take the child of a parent object, and use that smaller object to populate the larger one.  Starting to think this might be a bug with utility types in typescript.  Or maybe there's a disclaimer on them somewhere that I don't know about